# How to monitor a installed application?

Tags: blackberry, monitor, blackberry-jde

I want to monitor my installed application on Blackberry device and want to generate an email if user delete my application. we already have ping feature from application but need to know when user delete the application from device. 
Is there any way to do this?

Ali

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's posible.
I think you should consider regular pings so you can see active instalation and handle the inactive and uninstalled as equals.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Anyone else there?